# Half-Moon Betta fish tail-fin is curled in on itself, what could be the issue?

Tags: fish, betta

After having my beta for two weeks I noticed that his tail was curled in on itself, and when I had to net him to move him i noticed it got worse. He seems to swim fine but its just constantly curled in on itself, even partly when he's flaring. Was it damaged when i netted him or something else? There don't seem to be any visible tears. Here are some pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFH2N.jpg

Comment: it is hard to see in your pictures,if you turn off the lights in the room it will be easier to take good pictures of your fish.wellcome to pets.

Comment: It looks like there actually is a tear on the fin.